# Bootstrap toggle button works only once when clicked

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm having problems in the Bootstrap navigation menu. When I freshly reload my page, the toggle button works fine i.e. on click it shows the `li` items. However, after the first click, it does not work. In my Master page I already have a Navigation Menu of Bootstrap, which is working absolutely fine. The problem is occurring for my child page.

Here is my rendered code for the first time:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="tab">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" >
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="tabHeader">
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle align-center tabColor" id="divFavItemsTab" data-toggle onclick="ShowFavouriteNew();">
                        <asp:Literal ID="literalMyFav" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,lblMyFavorites %>"></asp:Literal>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle align-center tabColor" id="divMyItemsListTab" datatoggle onclick="ShowMyItemsNew();">
                        <asp:Literal ID="literalCmpitems" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,lblCompanyItem %>"></asp:Literal>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle align-center tabColor" id="divPackageTab" onclick="ShowPackagesNew();">
                        <asp:Literal ID="ltrlCmpPackages" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,lblPackage %>"></asp:Literal>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle align-center tabSelected" id="divOnlineTab" onclick="ShowOnlineNew();">
                        <asp:Literal ID="ltrlOnline" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,lblOnline %>"></asp:Literal>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is my code when I click on the toggle button:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="tab">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" >
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse in" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="tabHeader">
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle align-center tabColor" id="divFavItemsTab" data-toggle onclick="ShowFavouriteNew();">
                        <asp:Literal ID="literalMyFav" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,lblMyFavorites %>"></asp:Literal>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle align-center tabColor" id="divMyItemsListTab" datatoggle onclick="ShowMyItemsNew();">
                        <asp:Literal ID="literalCmpitems" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,lblCompanyItem %>"></asp:Literal>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle align-center tabColor" id="divPackageTab" onclick="ShowPackagesNew();">
                        <asp:Literal ID="ltrlCmpPackages" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,lblPackage %>"></asp:Literal>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle align-center tabSelected" id="divOnlineTab" onclick="ShowOnlineNew();">
                        <asp:Literal ID="ltrlOnline" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,lblOnline %>"></asp:Literal>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Up till now everything works fine, and I can see on click my `li` items. But this happens only for the first click. If I click again on the button so that these `li"` items get collapsed, they are not. I found out that `in` class as you can see above gets appended after first click is not being removed on second click. So what I did was I ran a jQuery like this:

```
$("#btnBsTab").click(function () {
    if ($("#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2").hasClass("in")) {
        $("#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2").removeClass("in");
    } else {
        $("#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2").addClass("in").css({height:'auto !important'});
    }
  });
});
```

Here `btnBsTab` is the button id, and I removed the `data-target` attribute from the code.
Now this works fine for me but I don't want to do like this way as bootstrap itself offers "data-target" functionality that actually handles div id on every click.

I am using jquery-1.9.0 and bootstrap 3.0.0 css and bootstrap.js also.

Comment: what does the rendered html look like - copy from html not from source asp

Comment: @TusharRaj, please move these comments into your original post and then delete them.  It is very hard to read code without proper spacing in comments.

Comment: ya please edit your questions @TusharRaj i cant read this!

Comment: @KyleMit I am really sorry people for posting my comments in such a manner.I have editted my post now .

Comment: @TusharRaj, no need to feel bad at all.  It just makes it more readable.  You can get rid of the comments now.